# jQuery ajax load div, wait for resources to load

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I have a vertically centered div. I use javascript to position it to the middle of the screen, so I need to know the height of the div.

Whenever I update the contents, I also need to reposition it. And here comes the problem. If I populate the div's content using ajax, it will complete the .html(), and the .load() function *before* any images are loaded. This will result in an errorous height detection.

How can I trigger a function when the div's full contents are loaded? Or when the div is resized (.resize() does not work)

Here is my code:

function loadpage(url)
{

```
$.get(url, function(data)
{
    $("#content").animate({left: '-400%'}, function() 
    {
        $("#content").html(data);
        var x = "-" + $("#content").height() / 2 + "px";

        console.log(x); 

        $("#content").css("top", x);

        $("#content").animate({left: '0%'}, function()
        {
        console.log($("#content").height()); 

        });



    });

});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

`.load()` won't work on dynamic rendering with ajax requests etc. To wait for the images to load you can use a plugin like:

- [batchImageLoad](https://www.google.com/search?q=batchImageLoad)
- [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages)